Approximating $\sqrt2$ by rationals using the Pigeonhole principle
Problem: For any positive integer $m$, I'd like to show that
there exist integers $a,b$ satisfying $|a|\leq m$, $|b|\leq m$ and
$0< a+b\sqrt{2}\leq \frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{m+2}\,$.
Solution attempt:
Define $M=\left\lbrace (m+2)\left(k+l \sqrt{2}\right)\,|\,0 \leq k,l \leq m \right\rbrace$,
then $|M| =(m+1)^2$.
Define $k=a_1+b_1\sqrt2$ and $l=a_2+b_2\sqrt2$.
By the Pigeonhole principle we can find $k,l$ such that
$|k-l\leq \frac{m\cdot (m+2)(1+\sqrt2)}{(m+1)^2-1}=1+\sqrt2\,$.
So we can choose $k,m$ such that $k-l=a_1-a_2+(b_1-b_2)\sqrt2$ because $\left |a_1-a_2\right | \leq m$ and $\left |b_1-b_2\right | \leq m\,$.
Am I right?
I'm not experienced with the Pigeonhole principle, and thank you for your help.

It is not clear, why "by Pidgeonhole principle we can find (distinct) $k$, $l$ such that
$\left |k-l\right|\leq \frac{m\cdot (m+2)(1+\sqrt2)}{(m+1)^2-1}=1+\sqrt2$".

You are on the right track, I'd say, but some important argumentation is still missing, and the second phrase in your solution attempt is faulty as it stands.
First realise that rational coefficients $p,q$ to give the real number
$\,p+q\sqrt2\,$ are uniquely determined:
If $p_1+q_1 \sqrt2 =$ $p_2+ q_2\sqrt2\,$ where
$p_1,q_1,p_2, q_2\in\mathbb Q,$ then necessarily
$p_2=p_1$ and $q_2=q_1$ because $\sqrt2\,$ is irrational.
This implies that the set
$\mathcal M :=\big\{a+b\sqrt{2}\;\big|\; a,b\in\{0,1,\dots, m\}\big\}$
has $(m+1)^2$ elements as distinct pairs of coefficients yield distinct elements due to uniqueness.
The smallest intervall containing $\mathcal M$ is
$\big[\,0\,, m\big(1+\sqrt2\,\big)\big]$. It is subdivided into
$m(m+2)=$ $(m+1)^2-1$ intervals of equal length $\frac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2}$,
to prepare for the pigeonhole principle.
Note that the first subdivision point
$\frac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2}\notin\mathcal M$, then choose the intervals
$$\left[\,0\,, \tfrac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2}\right),
\left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2},\, 2\,\tfrac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2}\right],
\left(2\,\tfrac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2},\, 3\,\tfrac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2}\right],
\:\ldots\:,
\left((m(m+2)-1)\tfrac{1+\sqrt2}{m+2},\, m\big(1+\sqrt2\big)\right].$$
They cover $\mathcal M$, hence one of these intervals contains at least two elements $a_1+b_1\sqrt{2}\,,\, a_2+b_2\sqrt{2}\in\mathcal M\,$
satisfying
$$0< (a_1-a_2)\,+\,(b_1-b_2)\,\sqrt 2\;<\;\frac{1+\sqrt 2}{m+2}$$
and $|a_1-a_2|,|b_1-b_2|\leqslant m$. Thus, the desired
$a=a_1-a_2$ and $b=b_1-b_2\in\mathbb Z$ exist.
The sharper than initial inequality on the right is due to the intervals being half-open.

You have written

Define $k=a_1+b_1\sqrt2$ and $l=a_2+b_2\sqrt2$.

I don't get this part because you have already written $0 \leq k,l \leq m$ where I think you meant $k,l$ are integers.
But they might be just typos. More importantly, I don't get the following part :

By Pidgeonhole principle we can find k,l such that
$\left |k-l\right|\leq \frac{m\cdot (m+2)(1+\sqrt2)}{(m+1)^2-1}=1+\sqrt2$

It seems to me that you forgot to consider $m+2$ since the elements of $M$ are of the form $(m+2)(k+l\sqrt 2)$.

I think what you were trying to do is as follows :
Proof :
In the following, we use $M$ that you defined.
From $0$ to $(m+2)(m+m\sqrt 2)$, there are $(m+1)^2$ elements of $M$. Splitting it into $(m+1)^2-1$ regions (note here that both $0$ and $(m+2)(m+m\sqrt 2)$ are the elements of $M$. See the end of this answer for the details), there are, by Pigeonhole principle, integers $k_1,k_2,l_1,l_2$ satisfying $$0\le k_1,k_2,l_1,l_2\le m$$
$$(k_1,l_1)\not=(k_2,l_2)$$ and
$$0\lt \underbrace{(m+2)(k_1+l_1\sqrt 2)}_{\text{an element of $M$}}-\underbrace{(m+2)(k_2+l_2\sqrt 2)}_{\text{an element of $M$}}\le \frac{(m+2)(m+m\sqrt 2)}{(m+1)^2-1}\tag1$$
(note that the left inequality holds since $(k_1,l_1)\not=(k_2,l_2)$)
Now, $(1)$ can be written as
$$0\lt (k_1-k_2)+(l_1-l_2)\sqrt 2\le \frac{1+\sqrt 2}{m+2}$$
Here, both $|k_1-k_2|\le m$ and $|l_1-l_2|\le m$ hold.

I'm going to add some explanations why we can say such integers exist.
We split $[0,(m+2)(m+m\sqrt 2)\color{red})$ (note here that $(m+2)(m+m\sqrt 2)$ is not included) into $(m+1)^2-1$ regions $$[0,1+\sqrt 2),[1+\sqrt 2,2(1+\sqrt 2)),\cdots, [(m^2+2m-1)(1+\sqrt 2),(m^2+2m)(1+\sqrt 2))$$
There are $(m+1)^2-1$ elements. (note that the element $(m+2)(m+m\sqrt 2)$ is excluded here)

If the region $[(m^2+2m-1)(1+\sqrt 2),(m^2+2m)(1+\sqrt 2))$ has an element, we are done.

If the region $[0,1+\sqrt 2)$ (which already has an element $0$) has an element which is not $0$, we are done.

Otherwise, by Pigeonhole principle ($(m+1)^2-2$ elements in $(m+1)^2-3$ regions), we are done.


